# Is it possible to implement a simple browser in Ionic/Angular or React Native?

Tags: angular, react-native, ionic-framework, browser

I would like to implement a little simple web browsing feature inside an Ionic/Angular or React-Native app. The browsing feature should happen inside my app with my navigation bar on top.

I know that it it theoretically possible with a simple iframe, but that would result in CORS errors on almost any page. Are there any working options or is a browser feature only possible within a real nativ Andoird / iOS app?

Many thanks in advance!
Jil

Comment: If you using "fetch" you can disable cors

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/

Answer (score 1):

With [Expo](https://expo.io/) (React Native), you can use the [Web Browser component](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/).

You should be able to also use [the in app browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) with Ionic.

Example with the Expo Web Browser (SDK 33):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, WebBrowser } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    result: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Open WebBrowser"
          onPress={this._handlePressButtonAsync}
        />
        <Text>{this.state.result && JSON.stringify(this.state.result)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _handlePressButtonAsync = async () => {
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://expo.io');
    this.setState({ result });
  };
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your fast reply @Poptocrack! : )

Quick followup question, would I be able to have my custom elements for the Ionic App Browser, e.g. custom back-button or custom url-input-field? (With custom I mean from an user interface point of view.)